# Facing error when calling Twitter rest API

Tags: angular, twitter

I am trying to call twitter rest APIs with oAuth 1.0 authentication. But I am getting forbidden error in every API. I want to call twitter following api in angular 8. Can someone let me know why I am getting this error and how can I resolve it.

I am getting below error:-

> { “client_id”: “21423516”, “detail”: “When authenticating requests to
> the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a
> Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a
> project via the developer portal.”, “title”: “Client Forbidden”,
> “required_enrollment”: “Standard Basic”, “reason”:
> “client-not-enrolled”, }

Answer (score 0):

Is the app inside of a project on the developer portal? That’s what the error message is asking about.

Comment: Actually, before the app was not inside the project, but I have placed the app inside the project when I got to know about it. And now I am able to access Twitter API, but now I am facing another issue. Can you please help with it?

Comment: I called https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/following API and it has called successfully. But I am facing the error when I pass other id in query params. It only accepts the Twitter user id of the user which I used to create a developer account. It doesn’t accept any other id.

My developer account userId is 1414937813116616705. so it only accepts this id. If I pass 798469166189547521 it is giving an error as below.

“message”: “The id query parameter value [798469166189547521] must be the same as the authenticating user [1414937813116616705]”

Answer (score -1):

All Twitter API v2 endpoints require requests to be authenticated with a set of credentials, also known as keys and tokens. You can use either OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token or OAuth 1.0a User Context to authenticate requests to these endpoints. OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token means that you must pass a Bearer Token with your request

Comment: Yes, I passed the correct authentication information. But it is giving an error. If I don't pass authentication it is giving an Unauthorized error and if I pass authentication error it is giving a Forbidden error.